# "Causes Harm" textarea extends beyond the modal dialog for Suggested Edit rejections

Tags: bug, review, suggested-edits

This is one of those classic "mixed up CSS" issues, so maybe it's nothing, but I'm using Chrome 39.0.2171.95, and I just addressed a suggested edit here on MSE, and the dialog for rejection looked like this:

[image]

As you can see, the "Describe how this edit would make the post worse" box extends beyond the width of the modal dialog.